# After ejecting app with Yarn doesn’t start anymore

Tags: reactjs, react-native, yarnpkg

I'm new to React Native and want to do some tutorials. But after I eject the project through:

```
yarn eject
```

I get this error in the terminal:

```
yarn run v1.13.0
$ react-native run-ios
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/joppemeijers/Documents/react/cashierr/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cliEntry.js:11:41)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Module._compile (/Users/joppemeijers/Documents/react/cashierr/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/Users/joppemeijers/Documents/react/cashierr/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

This is a whole new project and I didn't add anything. I searched on Google for some solutions but can't get it fixed, maybe some of you guys can help me?

Is there something I don’t have installed?

Comment: Have you got `@babel/runtime` installed?

Comment: @ııı how do i do this?

Comment: Try `yarn add @babel/runtime --dev`